# Remote connection to [null] failed with java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host in taskmanager

Tags: apache-flink

When I start my apache flink 1.10 taskmanager service in kubernetes(v1.15.2) cluster,it shows logs like this:

```
2020-05-01 08:34:55,847 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor            - Could not resolve ResourceManager address akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/resourcemanager, retrying in 10000 ms: Could not connect to rpc endpoint under address akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/resourcemanager..
2020-05-01 08:34:55,847 WARN  akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport                    - Remote connection to [null] failed with java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
2020-05-01 08:34:55,848 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123] has failed, address is now gated for [50] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123]] Caused by: [java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host]
2020-05-01 08:35:08,874 WARN  akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport                    - Remote connection to [null] failed with java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
2020-05-01 08:35:08,877 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123] has failed, address is now gated for [50] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123]] Caused by: [java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host]
2020-05-01 08:35:08,878 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor            - Could not resolve ResourceManager address akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/resourcemanager, retrying in 10000 ms: Could not connect to rpc endpoint under address akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/resourcemanager..
2020-05-01 08:35:21,907 WARN  akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport                    - Remote connection to [null] failed with java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
```

and the taskmanager could not registered success, and I logged into taskmanager and find out I could success ping jobmanager liket this:

```
flink@flink-taskmanager-54d85f57c7-nl9cf:~$ ping flink-jobmanager
PING flink-jobmanager.dabai-fat.svc.cluster.local (10.254.58.171) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from flink-jobmanager.dabai-fat.svc.cluster.local (10.254.58.171): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.045 ms
64 bytes from flink-jobmanager.dabai-fat.svc.cluster.local (10.254.58.171): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.076 ms
64 bytes from flink-jobmanager.dabai-fat.svc.cluster.local (10.254.58.171): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.079 ms
```

so why this would happen and what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install nmap in your kubernetes taskmanger's pod container:

```
apt-get udpate
apt-get install nmap -y
```

then scan the jobmanager and make sure the pod's expose port 6123 is accessable(in my case ,I found could not access the port 6123 from current pod).

```
nmap -T4 <your-jobmanager's-pod-ip>
```

Hope this help.